# DOM Dynamic Table calculation

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a table that is dynamically calculated when values are entered into cells.  The second and third cells of each column in the table are added to get the values in the 4th cell and all the values vertically should add up to get the totals at the bottom last cells.  There is one cell that isn't calculating correctly and I can't figure out why even after debugging.   The last cell in the last row and column calculates late and incorrect.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<table border="1" id="regionLead">
       <tr>
         <th colspan="4">Region Lead</th>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Region</td>
         <td>Deployed</td>
         <td>Vacant</td>
         <td>Total</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Eastern</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="easternDeployed" onchange="test.calculate()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="easternVacant" onchange="test.calculate()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="easternTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Southern</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="southernDeployed" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="southernVacant" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="southernTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Central</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="centralDeployed" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="centralVacant" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="centralTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Western</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="westernDeployed" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="westernVacant" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="westernTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Europe</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="europeDeployed" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="europeVacant" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="europeTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Asia</td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column1" id="asiaDeployed" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" class="column2" id="asiaVacant" onkeydown="test.hide()" style="background-color:#eee;width:55px"/></td>
         <td><div class="column3" id="asiatotalTotal">0</div></td>       
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Total</td>
         <td><div id="deployed"></div></td>
         <td><div id="vacant"></div></td>
         <td style="background-color:yellow"><div id="total"></div></td>      
       </tr>
    </table>


var allBoxes = 
document.querySelector("#regionLead");
calculate(allBoxes);

function calculate(tbl){
tbl.addEventListener("change", function(e){    
if (e.target.tagName === "INPUT"){
var rowNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  //console.log(rowNode);

  var rowInputs = 
 rowNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var tableNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;      
 // console.log(tableNode);
  /*get Deployed column of the table to add up*/
  var columnInputs = tableNode.getElementsByClassName('column1');

  /*get Vacant column of the table to add up*/      
  var columnInputs2 = tableNode.getElementsByClassName('column2');

  /*get Vacant column of the table to add up*/      
  var columnInputs3= tableNode.getElementsByClassName('column3');
  //alert(columnInputs3.length)
  var colSum = 0
  for(var i=0; i<columnInputs.length; i++){
    colSum += parseInt(columnInputs[i].value);
  }

  var colSum2 = 0
  for(var i=0; i<columnInputs2.length; i++){
    colSum2 += parseInt(columnInputs2[i].value);
  }      

  var colSum3 = 0
  for(var i=0; i<columnInputs3.length; i++){
    console.log(parseInt(columnInputs3[i].innerText));
    colSum3 += parseInt(columnInputs3[i].innerHTML);
  }  

  //Last cell in the deployed column
  tableNode.rows[8].cells[1].innerHTML = colSum;

  //Last cell in the vacan column
  tableNode.rows[8].cells[2].innerHTML = colSum2;     

  tableNode.rows[8].cells[3].innerHTML = colSum3;




  var rowDiv = rowNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var before = rowInputs[0].value || 0;
  var after = rowInputs[1].value || 0;
  if(before && after){      
      var total = parseInt(before)+parseInt(after);
      rowDiv[0].innerHTML = total; 
  }
}
 })
 }
```

https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/ebmrxv?editors=1011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

In line 44 of the Javascript code on Codepen, replace `colSum3` with `colSum + colSum2`.

So line 44 looks like this:

```
tableNode.rows[8].cells[3].innerHTML = colSum + colSum2;
```

This way, `colSum` and `colSum2` are dynamically added and the yellow grid cell is updated with the other ones.

(I still haven't figured out why `colSum3` doesn't update with `colSum` and `colSum2`.)

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick.  Not sure why I didn't think of that.  2 heads are better than 1.